# How to get the last hours in the interval of 5 mins in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I did this

```
var date, array = [];
date = new Date();

while (date.getMinutes() % interval !== 0) {
    date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + 1 );
}

// A whole day has 24 * 4 quarters of an hour
// Let's iterate using for loop
for (var i = 0; i < 24 * (60/interval); i++) {
    array.push(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes());
    date.setMinutes ( date.getMinutes() + interval);
}

console.log(array.slice(0,10));
```

I got the next hours in the interval of 5 mins.

Right now is `16:30`

```
(10) ["16:35", "16:40", "16:45", "16:50", "16:55", "17:0", "17:5", "17:10", "17:15", "17:20"]
```

How do I  adjusy my code to get the last hours in the interval of 5 mins ?

Right now is `16:30`, I want to get these

```
(10) ["16:25", "16:20", "16:15", "16:10", "16:05", "16:0", "15:55", "15:45", "15:35", "15:35"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move backwards instead of forwards, change your `+ interval` to `- interval`. To start rounded to the nearest 5 minutes in the *past* instead of the *future*, do your `setMinutes()` *before* pushing it to the array.

```
date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - interval);
array.push(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes());
```

```js
var date, array = [];
date = new Date();
const interval = 5;

while (date.getMinutes() % interval !== 0) {
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() + 1);
}

// A whole day has 24 * 4 quarters of an hour
// Let's iterate using for loop
for (var i = 0; i < 24 * (60 / interval); i++) {
  date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - interval);
  array.push(date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes());
}

console.log(array.slice(0, 10));
```